# Odd (or even) entries in a Ruby Array

Tags: ruby

Is there a quick way to get every other entry in an Array in Ruby? Either the odd or even entries values with 0 included in the odd. I'd like to be able to use it like this:

```
array1 += array2.odd_values
```

or

```
puts array2.odd_values.join("-")
```

for example

**Update**

This give exactly what I'm after but I'm sure there is a shorter version.

```
array1.each_with_index do |item,index| 
  if (index %2 ==0) then 
    array2.push(item) 
  end
end
```

Comment: Is this for display purposes?  If so, and if it's for the web CSS/javascript has a cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: This isn't exactly on target, but see my answer to a (vaguely) related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611431/small-question-on-scripting/1613746#1613746 Note that I included the `0th` element in the evens.

Comment: Not for the web I'm afraid. 

To be honest I'm just avoiding having a loop as I'm sure there will be a clever Ruby way of doing this.

Comment: Is it every other entry or or odd/even entries?

Comment: JRL - Every other entry

Essentially I have data that's off the form

info_type_a info_type_b info_type_a info_type_b etc. etc.




I just want to extract all the info_type_a or info_type_b

Answer (score 86, accepted):

```
a = ('a'..'z').to_a

a.values_at(* a.each_index.select {|i| i.even?})
# => ["a", "c", "e", "g", "i", "k", "m", "o", "q", "s", "u", "w", "y"]

a.values_at(* a.each_index.select {|i| i.odd?})
# => ["b", "d", "f", "h", "j", "l", "n", "p", "r", "t", "v", "x", "z"]
```

So, as requested

```
class Array
  def odd_values
    self.values_at(* self.each_index.select {|i| i.odd?})
  end
  def even_values
    self.values_at(* self.each_index.select {|i| i.even?})
  end
end
```

Comment: Dean, this includes `0` as the evens. This is inherent in using the `% 2` (or derivative) approach. I handle that in my reply.

Comment: Slightly faster to do: `a.values_at(*a.each_index.select(&:even?))`

Answer (score 72):

...

```
arr = ["0", "1", "2", "3"]
arr.select.each_with_index { |_, i| i.odd? }
arr.select.each_with_index { |_, i| i.even? }
```

As [floum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614147/odd-or-even-entries-in-a-ruby-array/13504376?noredirect=1#comment53210368_13504376) pointed out, in Ruby 2.2 you can simply do:

```
arr.select.with_index { |_, i| i.odd? }
```

Comment: I think select and each_with_index need to be the other way around for it to work -and in that case it'll return a list of tuples.

Comment: `arr.each_with_index.select { |str, i| i.odd? }.map(&:first)`, will sort out the tuples.

Comment: @Steve it works fine. No need to complicate such a simple piece of code. Keep it simple, and all that. Good point RE returning tuples.

Comment: Right you are. I was using this with ActiveRecord and forgot to put a `to_a` before `select` :flushed:

Comment: This should be faster than @glenn-jackman's answer because it only iterates over the array once, right?  Glenn's answer iterates twice.

Comment: I suggest `arr.select.each_with_index { |_, i| i.odd? }`, as the first argument to `each_with_index` is not actually used.

Comment: Actually, on Ruby 2.2, you just can go with `arr.select.with_index { |_, i| i.odd? }`

Comment: What does the underscore represent in `{ |_, i| i.odd? }`

Comment: @Bart_Judge it is used to indicate an unused argument. Quite a common convention across a few languages. Some more info here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147252/is-it-bad-practice-to-name-an-unused-variable-with-a-single-underscore

Answer (score 23):

```
left,right = a.partition.each_with_index{ |el, i| i.even? }
```

Comment: This is more elegant than the accepted answer IMHO.

Comment: Definitely the best answer

Comment: Just a FYI, you could use `with_index` instead of `each_with_index` in this solution.

Answer (score 18):

You can just use this:

```
(1..6).partition { |v| v.even? }  #=> [[2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5]]
```

From Ruby docs: [Ruby Docs Reference](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition)

Comment: very nice, should be top comment

Comment: except it doesn't act on indices, but array elements.  wrong.

Answer (score 9):

Some crazy way using facets:

```
require 'facets'
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
odd = array.to_h.keys # 1,3,5
even = array.to_h.values.compact # 2,4
```

Answer (score 8):

This will probably never be read, but...

Simple and clean:

```
array2.map{ |n| n if n % 2 == 0 }.compact # evens

array2.map{ |n| n if n % 2 == 1 }.compact # odds
```

Just found an even more terse way (gotta love Ruby):

```
array2.find_all{ |n| n % 2 == 0 } # evens

array2.reject  { |n| n % 2 == 0 } # odds
```

Comment: I think he wanted the array elements with odd indicies. This returns the array elements with odd *values*.

Comment: Also, `array.find_all(&:odd?)` is even terser!

Answer (score 5):

```
dst = []
array.each_slice(2) { |x| dst.push(x[1]) }
```

should give you an array of the odd indices.

Replace `x[1]` with `x[0]` for the even entries.

Comment: Seems to return a nil value 

>> array1.each_slice(2) { |x| x[1] }
=> nil
>>

Comment: That's an expensive eay to do it. The fastest is just to loop.

Comment: Hmmm... I guess it doesn't return a new array. Let me edit it.

Comment: @Chris: Of course a loop would be the faster, but why not just write it in ASM while we're at it too?

Answer (score 5):

For the record:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
h = Hash[*a]
evens = h.keys
odds = h.values
```

I'm using the 'splat' operator of Array to get comma separated values and pass that to Hash which accepts arguments as alternating keys/values.

Answer (score 4):

```
odds = array.each_slice(2).map(&:first)
evens = array.each_slice(2).map(&:last)
```

Comment: Close, except doesn't handle an array with an odd length. `[1,3,4].each_slice(2).map(&:last)` returns `[3,4]` but we want `[3]`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to think about it (adds array2 evens to array1):

```
array1 << array2.values_at(*Array.new(array2.size/2){|i| i*2})
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems like the most Rubyish solution, combining the best of JacobM and glenn jackman's approaches.

```
module ::Enumerable
  def select_with_index
    index = -1
    select { |x| yield(x, (index += 1)) }
  end
  def odds
    select_with_index {|x,i| i.odd?}
  end
  def evens
    select_with_index {|x,i| i.even?}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

With a blank array `A`, and a full array `H`, something like this should work:

```
H.size.times do |i|
  if i % 2 == 1
    A[i/2] = H[i]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you, or then again, not :-)

```
irb(main):050:0> all = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
irb(main):051:0> evens = []
=> []
irb(main):052:0> all.each_index do |i| if (i.even?): evens.push(a[i]) end end
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
irb(main):053:0> evens
=> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: ```(i.even?):``` -> ```(i.even?);```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [code snippet](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3746) that's intended to add a select_with_index method to Enumerable, which would allow you to do

`array.select_with_index{|item, i| item if i % 2 == 0}` for evens

`array.select_with_index{|item, i| item if i % 2 == 1}` for odds

Comment: you could use `if i.even?` and `if i.odd?`

Comment: that `(block_given? && self.class == Range || self.class == Array)` stuff in that snippet is nuts. Why not just `select { |x| index += 1; yield(x, index) }` ?

Answer (score 1):

My take on the problem, defining simple Array extensions:

```
class Array
  def odd_values
    (0...length / 2).collect { |i| self[i*2 + 1] }
  end

  def even_values
    (0...(length + 1) / 2).collect { |i| self[i*2] }
  end
end

puts [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ].odd_values.inspect
# => [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

puts [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ].even_values.inspect
# => [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]

puts [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ].even_values.inspect
# => [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]

puts [ ].even_values.inspect
# => []
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

(1...a.size).step(2).collect { |i| a[i] }
=> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

(2...a.size).step(2).collect { |i| a[i] }
=> [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Of course, considering 0 an odd index creates a little hackery, right? Since you will have adjacent entries that are in effect odd indicies. To compensate for that you can just add the zeroth entry to the result of the first collect. Consider:

```
[a[0]] + (1...a.size).step(2).collect { |i| a[i] }
=> [0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

You could always compact this further and do something like:

```
a.values_at(*(1...a.size).step(2))
=> [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

a.values_at(*(2...a.size).step(2))
=> [2, 4, 6, 8]
```

The same hack is available to handle the zeroth entry.

Comment: Why would you want 0 to be odd? 0 is even! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_zero

Comment: Because it was a requirement in the original request?

Answer (score 1):

```
evens = (1..10).each_with_object([]) {|i, a| a << i*2 }
#=> [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a.in_groups_of(2).map(&:first) => odds
a.in_groups_of(2).map(&:last) => evens
```

Comment: [`in_groups_of`](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/in_groups_of) is in Rails only. But [`each_slice`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_slice) in the Ruby standard library is equivalent here. So write `a.each_slice(2).map(&:first)`.

Comment: Note that “odds” in this answer (odd numbers in the array `a`) means the values at **even** indexes, and “evens” means values at odd indexes.

Answer (score 0):

```
module Enumerable
  def odd_values
    r = []
    self.each_index {|x| r << self[x] if x%2==0}
    r
  end
end

p ["a", "b" ,"c" ,"d" ,"e"].odd_values  #returns ["a","c","e"]
p ["a", "b" ,"c" ,"d" ,"e"].odd_values.join("-") #returns "a-c-e"
```

I just reused an approach i used for another question on arrays. :D

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget good old friend `Array.inject`

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
a.inject([]){|result, item| result << item if item %2 == 1; result}
```

Should give you odd items.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the use of Enumerable#Inject function

```
array = (1..30)    
array.inject({even: [], odd: []}){|memo, element| memo[element.even? ? :even : :odd] << element; memo}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly left field, but I recently needed something I could pass to `select` as a proc:

```
def alternator
  gen = [true,false].cycle
  proc { gen.next }
end

self.filter = alternator

# ... elsewhere/much later ...
input = 'a'..'z'
input.select(&filter)
```

Some may suggest this could even be a case for `Enumerator.new` or even a Fiber, which would both technically be simpler constructs, but I think at the expense of clarity.