# delete alternate elements of an array in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Odd ( or even ) entries in a Ruby array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614147/odd-or-even-entries-in-a-ruby-array)

Suppose i have a following array

```
arr = ["Value0","Value1","Value2","Value3","Value4","Value5","Value6","Value7","Value8"]
```

I want to delete the alternate element such that my o/p array will something like following

```
["Value0", "Value2", "Value4", "Value6", "Value8"]
```

i.e it should delete the elements at the odd position.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't feel it is the fastest way but you could do

```
>> arr.reject {|v| arr.index(v).odd?}
#=> ["Value0", "Value2", "Value4", "Value6", "Value8"]
```

or

```
>> arr.each_slice(2).map(&:first)
#=> ["Value0", "Value2", "Value4", "Value6", "Value8"]
```

Comment: `arr.each_slice(2).map(&:first)` is a nicer version of the second one.

Comment: Definitly! I'll change it, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

```
arr.reject!.with_index{|_, i| i.odd?}
```

or

```
arr.select!.with_index{|_, i| i.even?}
```

Comment: Nice one. I did not know you could do that.

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = ["Value0","Value1","Value2","Value3","Value4","Value5","Value6","Value7","Value8"]
flag = false
p arr.select!{flag = !flag}
#=> ["Value0", "Value2", "Value4", "Value6", "Value8"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr1 = arr.clone
arr.each_with_index {|el,index| arr1.delete_at(index) if index % 2 > 0 }
```

or

```
arr1 = []
arr.each_with_index {|el,index| arr1 << el if index % 2 == 0}
```